# Why is Classic ASP considered something from the Dark Ages?

Tags: asp-classic

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88556/how-to-make-classic-asp-interesting-if-you-are-stuck-with-it

One fellow used the term Dark Age.  I know he is right, but I do not know why.  I am aware the Microsoft will continue to support Classic ASP.  I do not know how to sell this to the powers that be.  After all, it does still work.  I can't just develop for a resume.  I'm not going anywhere anyway.  But I do try and keep a current skillset.

There was no tag for Dark Ages.

Answer (score 4):

Supporting classic ASP and actively developing / expanding it's role are two different things. Classic ASP is not being improved upon so as the architectures that these systems run on increases (64 bit memory space, 8 or 12 core CPUs, etc), you won't be able to take advantage of them. Also interoperability ends up being a pain as instead of someone writing a library wrapper you have to interop yourself directly, leading to longer development times. Finally, developers are no longer actively training themselves in a tech, it means it's expensive to hire new people to work on a project because fewer and fewer developers are programming in it.

Overall, it's an expensive cost to refactor up-front, but you end up being bled dry as you are using way more hardware than you might need, paying someone well above market rate to maintain it, etc.

But to answer your resume question, you should be self-teaching outside of work and doing side projects. Build a web portfolio of cool projects in .NET or Ruby and you will be able to get a new job.

Comment: I was saying I'm not going to develop for a resume.  I'm not going anywhere.  I needed "real" justification.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, I guess I read your question wrong re: resumes. Also good ammo is to know that part of developing these days is drawing upon online resources and code examples, which are less and less available as the communities around legacy software atrophy.

Comment: I think there are two factors.  Open source developers hate it because it's by Microsoft, and Microsoft themselves want developers to drop it in favour of .net.  It still has plenty of supporters though.  http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2011/10/asp-why-am-i-still-using-it.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, newer and better things have been made. While this doesn't exactly mean that Classic ASP isn't useful anymore, the community has moved away from it and won't want much to do with it anymore.

What that comment meant is that the company should have updated, and because they didn't, their code was unreadable to many modern programmers.